# using Jquery selector with an array

Tags: jquery, arrays, jquery-selectors

i am trying to use jquery selector with and array of objects.
here is an example..

```
//Declaration
    var filterItems = Array();
    filterItems[0] = { clickDiv: "CategoryPanelHeader", div: "NarrowByCategoryPanelWrapper" };
    filterItems[1] = { clickDiv: "ExpandYourResultsHeader", div: "ExpandResultPanelWrapper" };
    filterItems[2] = { clickDiv: "Keyword", div: "KeywordDiv" };
    filterItems[3] = { clickDiv: "Manufacturer", div: "NarrowByManufacturerPanelWrapper" };
    filterItems[4] = { clickDiv: "Credentials", div: "CredentialsDiv" };
```

and the selector

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  //binds the click events...
  for (var i = 0; i < filterItems.length; i++) {
     $('#'+ filterItems[i].clickDiv).live('click', function () {
     togglemenu($('#' + filterItems[i].div));
     });
  }
});
```

i am able to read each item properly when i make an alert but jquery is not binding the click events.

how would i go about using an array to bind the onclick events?

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: i am using jquery 1.8.14

Comment: As oGeez said. Try [`.on`](https://api.jquery.com/on/) instead, see if that makes a difference.

Comment: .on instead of .live  make an error
P.S. see above i edited the ver. i am using 1.8.14

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures#Creating_closures_in_loops.3A_A_common_mistake

Comment: if you are using live use jquery 1.7.2 version

Comment: `$(document).ready(function () {
    $.each(filterItems, function (i, item) {
        $(document).on('click', '#' + item.clickDiv, function () {
            togglemenu($('#' + item.div));
        });
    })
});`

Comment: arun that code still does not work.. i can see all the items in the the array  but they are not binding properly

Comment: if is move the event to the onclick event i can get the divs to toggle.. but they all toggle at once.. not individualy

Answer (score 0):

i got it!
you just have to call an outside function

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
            // gets all the click parameters...
            for (var i = 0; i < filterItems.length; i++) {
                bindClicks(($('#' + filterItems[i].clickDiv)), ($('#' + filterItems[i].div))  );
            }
        });
           function bindClicks(clickdiv, expanddiv) {
             //binds the click events
            clickdiv.click(function () {
                togglemenu(expanddiv);
            });
        }
```